# XmlTextWriter c# prints also html source code of the page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xmltextwriter

i have this function for generating an xml file.. the problem is that when i download the generated file, i have my xml correctly formatted but at the end of this also the html source code of the page where i have clicked the button for generate this. What is the problem? Here the source code:

```
protected void lnkEsporta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Eventi> lista_eventi = //load list

        string filename = "~/data/eventi.xml";



        XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath(filename), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
        tw.Flush();
        tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        tw.WriteStartDocument();
        tw.WriteStartElement("wrapper");
        tw.WriteElementString("project", GetDao().Get<Progetti, Int32>(lista_eventi[0].idprogetto).nome);

        tw.WriteStartElement("events");

        foreach (Eventi evento in lista_eventi)
        {
            tw.WriteStartElement("event");

            tw.WriteElementString("idEv", evento.idev.ToString());
            tw.WriteElementString("data", evento.DataInizio.ToString());
            tw.WriteElementString("sede", evento.sede.ToString());
            tw.WriteElementString("location", evento.location.ToString());
            tw.WriteElementString("video", evento.video ? "True" : "False");
            tw.WriteElementString("tutors", evento.tutors.ToString());
            tw.WriteElementString("technicians", evento.technicians.ToString());

            tw.WriteStartElement("aule");

            List<Aule> lista_aule = //load list
            foreach (Aule aula in lista_aule)
            {
                tw.WriteElementString("aula", aula.descrizione.ToString(), aula.idaula.ToString());
            }

            tw.WriteEndElement();

            tw.WriteEndElement(); //end of source event
        }

        tw.WriteEndElement();//end of source events
        tw.WriteEndElement();//end of source wrapper

        tw.WriteEndDocument();//end of source tag

        tw.Close();


        Response.ClearContent();
        //Response.End();
        Response.Clear();

        Response.StatusCode = 200;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        //Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _Buffer.Length.ToString());

        Response.ContentType = "application-download";


        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filename));




    }
```

i have at the beginning my xml and after this it starts with page source code... what can i do? thank you very much for your help!

Comment: One thing to note: `XmlWriter` is a pain compared with creating an in-memory XML document and then writing it out. Unless you're *really* expecting huge documents, I would just use LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you are missing `Response.End()`.

See also [Filename and mime problems - ASP.NET Download file (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526104/filename-and-mime-problems-asp-net-download-file-c)

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("inline; filename={0}.xml", Path.GetFileName(Path)));

    Response.WriteFile(path); // 
    Response.Flush();
    // Response.Close(); // end should do this anyway so optional
    Response.End(); // end forces the server to send the request immediately. Failing to
```

Comment: I notice the StatusCode gets set to 200 in the code. This might also be a problem as probably results in the output being interpreted as an HTML page rather than a file stream.