# ZIP file download tries to download page

Tags: asp.net, zip

just putting this out there to see if anyone has any good off-the-cuff suggestions.

I have a web page with a button that triggers the download of a PDF file. When I run this page up in development from within VS I get the file coming back for download as expected, however since moving my web site to a staaging environment it is now yielding a very different result: When I click the download button I instead get an error and a message which seems to indicate that the call actually attempted to download the raw ASPX page rather than any ZIP file.

[image]

As this works so painlessly in my development environment, I'm assuming this must be down to environmental/configurational differences. Has anybody come across this before and if so could you inform me of the error of my ways?

Many thanks in advance
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Could the aspx file be the actual zipfile ? Have you tried downloading it and open as zip?
Does the server allow for aspx to execute, eg mime-settings ?

Maybe this helps [Filename and mime problems - ASP.NET Download file (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526104/filename-and-mime-problems-asp-net-download-file-c)
Or look here [How to retrieve and download server files (File.Exists and URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384649/how-to-retrive-and-download-server-files-file-exists-and-url)